# TFS Build error after installing Visual Studio 2015 Update 1

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfsbuild

I installed Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 onto our build server and now I am getting errors copying the Typescript/Javascript files after the compilation completes.

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets(182,5):
>   error MSB3021: Unable to copy file "C:\Builds\1\XXX\XXX Continuous
>   Integration\src\XXX\Trunk\XXX\XXX.Web\Content\Scripts\Admin\Reports.js"
>   to "C:\Builds\1\XXX\XXX Continuous
>   Integration\bin_PublishedWebsites\XXX.Web\C:\Builds\1\XXX\XXX
>   Continuous
>   Integration\src\XXX\Trunk\XXX\XXX.Web\Content\Scripts\Admin\Reports.js".
>   The given path's format is not supported.

It looks like the output path is being built incorrectly - the output directory is being added a second time.  Has anyone else had this issue after upgrading to Visual Studio 2015 Update 1?

Comment: Are you using TFS 2015 Update1? Are you using XAML build or vNext build? Could you provide your steps? I'd like to reproduce your scenario to see whether I can get the same issue.

Comment: We have the same issue. On buildserver I applied VS2015 update 1, but TFS is 2013. It looks as problem of interpretation of command line of tsc 1.7, not problém of tfs itself. With TS 1.6.3 it worked well. Build ddefinition and "TypeScript Build" tab in project remained teh same.

Comment: Issue on Github: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5894

Comment: Can you send me diagnostic build logs so I can try to figure out what's happening? paul(dot)van(dot)brenk(at)Microsoft(dot)com

The issue on GitHub, actually revers to VS 2013, not VS 2015.

Comment: https://github.com/JiriZidek/Garbage/blob/master/Broken_build_TS17.zip

Comment: Thanks, but I need the 'diagnostic' log, which you can create when you use the `/v:diagnostic /fl` command line options for msbuild.

Comment: @PaulvanBrenk Same error here with VS 2015 (no TFS involved) running package command on an Azure project. VS2015 update 1 + Azure SDK 2.8 + Typescript 1.7.

Comment: One scenario this happens is when `$(OutDir)` is specified in the project file, which generally only happens on build servers. I checked in a fix for that. and we're working on getting a release out, so you can validate against your scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is fixed in Typescript version 1.7.6.  Upgrade to resolve the build issue.

Comment: Upgrade TFS or Visual Studio? I was wondering if we need to install the TypeScript update on the Build Server.

Answer (score 2):

**Solved by 1.7.6 release of typescript:** http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=717098

**Obsolete:**

As a workaround I found two options:

A) Precompile (legacy)
- TS files mark as Content
- precompile TS to JS & MAP on dev VS, include in project, check-in

B) In TypeScript build tab use "Combine Javascript output info one file" and set to Scripts\app.js

Answer (score 2):

Workaround:

1) Create publish profile "**Web Deploy Package**"

2) Add to your build definition:

```
/p:Disable_CopyWebApplication=True /p:DeployOnBuild=true; 
PublishProfile=publish_profile_name
```

Comment: This worked for me.  Though it might not work for everyone else depending on other settings being used.  It looks like the proper fix will have to come from the TypeScript team.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'm seeing this too (though locally — we do not use TFS, but we use a checked-in `Microsoft.WebApplication.targets` file) after installing Update 1. It actually copies the files fine to disk for me, but the build fails and ends prematurely. Also, the error messages are only generated for 16 files (`.js`, `.js.map`) out of several hundred, in a certain directory/TypeScript module. I'm not sure if it's just quashing the rest of the errors, but I tried renaming the directory name in case something was up with its name (it was named `Common`). No dice.

Answer (score 0):

As a workarround you could disable copy to _PublishedWebsites by adding an MSBuild argument to your TFS build definition like this:

```
/p:Disable_CopyWebApplication=True
```

Comment: In fact we use only _PublishedWebsites content, so we cannot disable its generation...

Comment: As a sidenote if you want to disable _PublishedWebsites for good you can place the following inside the .csproj of the project involved: <Disable_CopyWebApplication>True</Disable_CopyWebApplication>

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure we had the same issue, but I followed @Paul advice and upgraded. That worked for sure.

I'm posting here because I had to upgrade "TypeScript for Visual Studio 2015"
on the TFS Build Server and wanted to make that clear.

Here's the link to the 2.0 upgrade https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593