# Error Copying Typescript files when packaging Azure project - Visual Studio 2015 Update1

Tags: azure, msbuild, typescript, visual-studio-2015

After updating to VS 2015 Update 1 (including Typescript 1.7) and the Azure SDK 2.8, I am unable to package my Azure application for deployment because of an error in the path the packager is trying to copy the js output file to:

> Error     Unable to copy file "D:\X\XX\XXX\App\services\editor\ruler-manager.js" to "D:\X\XX\XXX\obj\Debug\PE.Web\D:\X\XX\XXX\App\services\editor\ruler-manager.js". The given path's format is not supported.    PE.Architecture C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.8\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets  2787

Note that the directory has been included twice, causing an illegal colon in the middle of the output path.

It seems likely this is related to [TFS Build error after installing Visual Studio 2015 Update 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34048228/1014822) and https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/300a59bc-0f23-41a4-927a-05ae9978f3a4/unable-to-build-project-with-tyepscript-since-upgrading-to-vs-2015-update-1?forum=msbuild&prof=required and https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5894

**Update:**
The following workaround has been suggested, but we were still unable to publish after implementing it:

> We worked around it by manually adding ContinueOnError="WarnAndContinue" to the Copy task within the CopyWebRoleFiles target, within Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets.

(Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5894#issuecomment-162261090)

Does anyone have any workarounds or fixes other than the ones suggested in the linked threads?

Comment: I'm hitting this problem too. Same scenario: TypeScript with VS 2015 Update 1, trying to publish to Azure Cloud Service. VS says, "the given path's format is not supported." And, like the parent poster, it's showing the directory included twice, causing an illegal colon in the middle of the path.

Comment: There's a workaround suggested on GitHub https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5894#issuecomment-162261090 but we didn't see any change in the error after trying it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a bug in the Typescript 1.7 tooling. Fixes have been released:

For [VS 2015](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=717098) (TS 1.7.6)

For [VS 2013](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=717464) (TS 1.7.5)

Details here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5894#issuecomment-163798025