# VSTS/VSO Host Pool: The given path's format is not supported

Tags: tfsbuild, azure-devops

We are using VSO/VSTS' host build pool with the new vNext build platform. But suddenly, as of today, all of our builds have started breaking. This happens during the execution of a powershell script.

**Error:**

> . 'C:\a\1\s\scripts\LocalPublish.ps1' --packOutput C:\a\1\a\MyProject --projectName "MyProject.Api" --buildConfiguration Release
>
> Executing the following powershell script. (workingFolder = C:\a\1\s)
>
> C:\a\1\s\scripts\LocalPublish.ps1 --packOutput C:\a\1\a\MyProject --projectName "MyProject.Api" --buildConfiguration Release
>
> Microsoft .NET Development Utility Clr-x86-1.0.0-rc1-16231
>
> [error]Error: The given path's format is not supported.
>
> [error]Process completed with exit code 1 and had 1 error(s) written to the error stream.

**Powershell script arguments:**

> --packOutput $(build.stagingDirectory)\MyProject --projectName "MyProject.Api" --buildConfiguration $(BuildConfiguration)

Can anyone explain why this has started happening?

Comment: I'm getting the same problem. I'll add a post for the VSTS/VSO forums and hopefully someone will answer there.

Comment: Actually I'm wrong - its not the same error, just a similar one.

This is the one I am getting:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34100740/error-copying-typescript-files-when-packaging-azure-project-visual-studio-2015

Except it is on the VSO/VSTS's build pool

Comment: I've added a post to the Visual Studio Online forum https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a631ca36-611e-4cdc-9fb1-421e6e9afb56/new-build-errors-when-building-web-role?forum=TFService

Comment: @PhilMartin: Check my answer.  I also replied to your MSDN post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that a backwards incompatible change was introduced. From how I understand it, passing in parameters can now only be done using a single dash '-' and not a double dash '--'.

Build works when arguments are as follows:

> -packOutput $(build.stagingDirectory)\MyProject -projectName "MyProject.Api" -buildConfiguration $(BuildConfiguration)