# ##[error]The given path's format is not supported

Tags: nuget, tfs-2015

I am trying to setup build definition in TFS 2015 .WHen i try to setup build ,it's failing and giving below error:

MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'.
12. 2017-03-31T13:59:36.1211815Z ##[error]The given path's format is not supported.
13. 2017-03-31T13:59:36.1368100Z ##[error]Unexpected exit code 1 returned from tool NuGet.exe

I tried selecting restore nuget package as well as everything I could do but I am not getting which path's format is being fetched. Please help me.

Comment: The error is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/34048228. The answer may help you find a solution.

Comment: It didn't resolve my issue..I m still getting the same error.....I don't know which path is being taken and what format is this ?

Comment: Which build definition are you setting, the old XAML build or the new vNext build?

Comment: What is the version of nuget.exe you use on the build machine? Can you share the detailed logs?

Answer (score 0):

This error is similar to [Nuget 3.4+ can not restore some packages fails with "The given path's format is not supported"](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3434)

First, please check  nuget.config and make sure nuget can find packages from your sources. Besides if you are using Nuget 3.4.x, give a try with version `3.5.0-rtm-1829`

Comment: Still getting the same error..When we disable nuget installer and just run MSBuild utility ..build gets completed without any output.

Comment: @abhinavchaturvedi The issue seems to be related to nuget install task. Could your share your task settings and the nuget.config file?